# Invalid package file Android

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application on Play market/Store. Recently I sent some updates to the same and one user responded with an ***Invalid package file*** error while updating the application. After Googling around I found out that this might be a problem with the network or the device cache for the market application. However I want to make sure that there is no discrepancy on part of the development team. How do I go about resolving this? What causes the error and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem for all users with Android 2.3 after updating my app. Things like clearing the Play Store cache don't work, so it seems to be a development issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

Go to settings.

Head over to applications.

Open all applications/manage applications.

Move onto Google Play Store.

Simply clear data and clear cache.

Comment: I am asking for a developer perspective, not a user perspective. Thanks anyways, I had Googled the same earlier!

Comment: It all started for us when we went to android studio. I am scrubbing the final manifest for filtering issues that a module might be introducing...  it's just a  lead but I don't have time to do more research... I'll be following this question to see where it goes.