# "Package file is invalid", solution from the developer side (Android)

Tags: android, installation, package

I'm tired to see a lot of Stackoverflow questions about this, even in Google forums or Google official support site, publishing "solutions" that lead to uninstall package through ADB, to do something with the phone rooted, to delete cache of Google Play Services, etc ...

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64514
- https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3300875?hl=en
- http://gizmostorm.com/how-to-fix-package-file-is-invalid-error-on-google-play-store/
- https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=android%20upgrade%20download%20invalid%20package ...
- etc ...

Is there any solution from the package side ?

I mean, I have an app with hundreds of thousands of installs, and unfortunately many users are complaining about this error when upgrading from store my new version.

Obviously, I can not go one by one telling they have to do this or that, because they are not developers, they just want to upgrade and run an app !

Some users are telling me (complaining) this happened since the last "upgrade attempt" of my app, and they are not experiencing this "package file is invalid" with any other app in their phones.

So, I guess it's something I can fix with another upgrade.

Is there ANY SOLUTION that I can do in the next APK compilation, uploading to Google Play Store and fix this without "bothering" my users ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673024/invalid-package-file-android#comment26259600_17939273

Comment: One cause of this can be some ART/Dalvik incompatibilities?

Comment: What do you mean ? I've been always using the same Eclipse and Android SDK

Comment: There is no work around for this, I have same issue but i have observed that this issue comes only in non popular devices so i left as it is. I know its not good but cant do anything in this.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same issue in my project as well. I was adding many more features with new jar, git open source library code for Nice UI.

For searching for solution  I found play store has issue in one of its updates 
http://www.androidcentral.com/google-investigating-package-file-invalid-errors-google-play
But this is totally not relevant to my problem

Again searching I found this
http://birbit.com/how-to-solve-linearalloc-problem/
So the solution looks to be loading a few jar files dynamically using DexClassLoader.
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

1. Prepare Interface of the jar file (list of all classes and methods) and have the interface in the app - Need to see how to do this. - We can just have those classes which we need in our app and ignore the rest of the classes. This way we can implement for few existing jars and any new jars that we have to add to make sure we don’t run into this issue again.
2. Keep the jar in assets folder
3. Load every class from the jar (based on the list of jars we have in the interface). (The classes will be loaded just once on first launch)

But Based on this, this looks to be involving lot of coding changes and a time consuming things.

Moreover I found that facebook also faced same issue in their initial android app
https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/under-the-hood-dalvik-patch-for-facebook-for-android/10151345597798920

Final Approach I took was removing additional code from jar/git library project which is not require for my application. after that my app got install on 2.3.X with no error.